# Hangfire Dashboard in .Net Core Web API Project

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

We have a .Net Core 2.0 Web API project. I have added the hangfire there. We don't have any web page in the project and I use JWT for authorization. So I'm not able to do the authorization for hangfire using the Authorize(DashboardContext context). Is there any way we can pass some sort of API key on the url to authorize the user for dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using cookies, I will explain the idea to you with some code...
Firstly once the user login (you generate the token) you must store the token you generated to cookies in the browser and then when you want to access to Hangfire dashboard you must read the token from cookies and then check the roles...

- the code to store the token in cookies:

`

```
httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", userToken.AccessToken,
new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6000) });
```

`

- make sure you enabled cookies by:

`

```
AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddJwtBearer(cfg => your configs);
```

`

- then the authorize method will be like this:

`

```
public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
{
            var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
                var jwtToken = string.Empty;  
        
                if (httpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("token"))
                {
                    httpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("token", out jwtToken);
                }
                else
                    return false;
        
        
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwtToken))
                {
                    return false;
                }
        
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        
                try
                {
                    var claim = _tokenService.GetClaimsPrincipal(jwtToken);
                    return claim != null && claim.IsInRole(RolesConstants.ADMIN);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    throw exception;
                }
}
```

`

Answer (score -3):

Implement an IAuthorizationDashboardFilter class.
Try this post [here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/using-bearer-auth-token/2166/4).
You need to pass JWT token with each request, try storing token in a cookie or as a query string parameter. Then you can pull that from request context and decide whether user is authorized

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
     public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
     {
       var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
       var token = context.Request.Cookies["access-token"];
       // check token validity and set authentication accordingly. 
       return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
   }
}
```

Register the filter in your OWIN pipeline like this,  after whatever authentication method you are using. Then the logged in user claim will be available in the filter

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(...); // Authentication - first
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
    {
         Authorization = new [] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() }
    });       // Hangfire - last
}
```

Comment: Like he said, he is using JWT authentication which does not make use of the HttpContext object. This doesn't work.

Comment: I'd love an answer to this also

Comment: Sorry for replying late on this. edited the answer with a possible solution for JWT token.